# Is Google Analytics available without "ejecting" the React Native app

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-analytics

Recently, Google has sent a message claiming "the older style of Google Analytics for mobile apps[, Google Analytics for mobile apps reporting,] and the Google Analytics Services SDK ... will begin to sunset ..." It goes on to suggest that Google will replace the old UA-based tracking with a Firebase version.

I use React Native and the app is not ejected, yet. The team doesn't want to eject the app. Is there any package or procedure in place that will allow the app to report view opens/navigations to Google Analytics without ejecting the app?